# Java и совместимость

Tags: java, java-8, совместимость, java-10

Мне очень нравится нововведение в `java 10` - `var`. И если я правильно понимаю, то вся "магия" происходит именно на этапе компиляции. Т.е. бинарный код никак не будет отличаться от эквивалентного кода, собранного для, скажем, окружения версии 8.

Есть ли возможность использовать `var`, но при этом компилировать под жаву `8`? (Что-то вроде `-source 10 -target 8`)?

Answer (score -1):

Нет такой возможности. Лучше просто дождаться следующего Long Time Support (LTS) релиза Java 11 в конце этого месяца и использовать полноценную поддержку `var`, которая претерпела там дополнительное улучшение.